# Testing beta is 1 with Minitab or SPSS

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, spss, minitab

I would like to run a regression to test a hypothesis that alpha = 0 and Beta = 1. I understand minitab or SPSS regression will test whether alpha or beta is 0.

How do I test whether beta is equal to 1 using either one of the softwares?

Without needing to do extra calculation or changing the equation, is there a way to do regression(to test beta=1) using either one of these softwares ? I understand it can be done with eviews. Any “tricks” available with SPSS or Minitab?

Comment: Look and see if the software lets you specify an offset. If it does there is a solution depending on exactly how it implements it but detailed coding advice is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any idea where I might find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to run a normal regression (test beta is zero), then based the results manually recalculate t test to see if beta is one ? Slope minus 1 divided by standard error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SPSS in the GLM or UNIANOVA procedures pretty easily. In the menus, click Analyze>General Linear Model>Univariate. Specify the dependent variable and specify the independent variable as a covariate. Click the Paste button. If y is the dependent and x the predictor, you'll see something like:

UNIANOVA y WITH x
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(0.05)
  /DESIGN=x.

Edit it to read:

UNIANOVA y WITH x
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(0.05)
  /DESIGN=x
  /LMATRIX x 1
  /KMATRIX 1.

With the cursor anywhere in that command, click the Run button.

The LMATRIX subcommand specifies a custom hypothesis test, with 1 times the beta coefficient for the x predictor as the estimand to be tested. The KMATRIX says to compare that to 1 rather than the default value of 0.

Look in the Custom Hypothesis Tests #1 section of the output for your results.